# Can the NSMultableArray mention which object inside the NSMultableArray?

Tags: objective-c, arrays

The NSMutableArray can store every NSObject, but can I mention the NSMutableArray can get store my item only, for example, a NSMutableArray that store NSString only?
I remember that the java array can do that, can the objective C array do the similar things? Thanks.

Comment: so you dont want any other objects but NSString in your Array? is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objective-C does not have this kind of generic constraint on NSArray/NSMutableArray. You have therefore two solutions:

- [Subclass NSArray/NSMutableArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) and check for element type. It is strongly discouraged as NSArray/NSMutableArray is a class "cluster" and not obvious to subclass.
- [Create a category](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW1) with specific methods that check the right type. You will have a compile-time enforcement of the type.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this -

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
if([obj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
    [arr addObject:obj];
```

This way you end up adding only `NSString` to your arr.

Answer (score 0):

Not by default, no.  NSArray and its mutable counterpart just store pointers which happen to point obj-c objects.  These objects can of any type.  It would be up to you to make sure that only NSString's get in your array.

You could potentially subclass NSArray and override the addObject: methods such that they throw an exception if you try to add a non-NSString object.